# Detect wether machine is 32 or 64 bits

Tags: 64-bit

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and it has `amd e2 vision`  processor

I don't know know if my machine is 64-bit or 32-bit so I am having confusion downloading the UBUNTU version (64 or 32 bit)

Can anybody help??

Comment: AMD E2 series are 64bit processors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-E-Series-E2-1800-Notebook-Processor.73564.0.html (and also in the other E2 models listed). The [AMD page](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/processors/notebook-tablet/e-series-apu) itself is of not much use in this regard.